# Why does the way we write the matrix for a linear transformation differ here?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

T: $R^{3} -> R^3$ with $T(x_1, x_2, x_3) $ = $(-x_1 + x_2 - x_3, -4x_2 + 6x_3, -3x_2 + 5x_3) $
then our linear transformation for T is $$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & -4 & 6 \\ 0 & -3 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

but according to my problem sheet when we find this linear transformation:
V is the vector space of polynomials of degree at most 3 in R. p(x) in V
T(p(x)) = p(1+x) - p'(1-x).

I have applied the transformation to the basis ${1, x, x^2, x^3}$ however it feels like when we find this matrix it feels like we are transposing and not ordering the elements in the same way as above.

what I mean by this is that for example $T(1) = 1 + 0 \times [{x, x^2, x^3}]$ however according to the answers on my problem sheet this is the first column not the first row. Whereas in the first example our first element of the transformation is a row vector.

My answer to this second transformation is basically the transpose of what it is supposed to be and I don't understand why.

Comment: It looks like you're using row vectors to represent the polynomials instead of column vectors, and this should account for the apparent transposed matrix.

Comment: How can a linear transformation be a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example the first component is just a number. It is determined from the coefficients, which aren't given yet. But if you specify some coefficients then it collapses to just a number, for example $T(1,2,3)$ will have first component $-1+2-3=-2$.

In your second example you are already plugging in coefficients, specifically $(1,0,0,0)^T$ in the monomial basis, so you get back a single polynomial (namely the polynomial $x \mapsto 1$).

That said, in general the columns of a matrix representation of a linear transformation are the values given by plugging in the basis elements, in other words the $k$th column of the matrix representation of $T$ will correspond to $T(e_k)$ where $e_k$ is the $k$th element of the basis for the domain. So in the second example, the fact that $T(1)=1 + 0x + 0x^2 + 0x^3$ will appear in the first column of the matrix representation. You should try to understand why that has to be; IMO you won't really understand matrix representations of linear transformations without both understanding this fact and how it comes about from the definitions.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense.